# Error When Installing ADF Plugin in Oracle Fusion Cloud on the Excel

Tags: excel, oracle, plugins, cloud, fusion

We are getting following error in Oracle Excel

Error When Installing Oracle ADF Plugin: "Customized functionality in this application will not work because the certificate used to sign the deployment manifest for Oracle ADF Plug-in or its location is not trusted."

[image]

Please let me know if you have know this issue?

Or any links that could help me resolve this.

Regards,
Raghu Ariga

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot does not seem to be related to the Oracle ADF Excel add-in.

You may want to uninstall this "GoToMeeting" add-in temporarily.

On the other hand, if you are really trying to get past this message, you should take the error at face value: the certificate from the add-in shown has not yet been added to the trust store.

Here's a Microsoft article on trusted publishers:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-remove-or-view-a-trusted-publisher-87b3d5a3-b68c-4023-87c4-7cc78a44d7ed